# You can not convert CjwKEAjwiYG9BRCkgK-G45S323oSJABnykKAhI-

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I intend to run my script on Google sheet

What I'm doing is to restore the values ​​of the cells, and use an if statement to compare an identifier cell with another userid cell.

If they are different, I want to eliminate that entire row, if they are equal I want to leaving the entire row as it is.

I get the error:

> You can not convert CjwKEAjwiYG9BRCkgK-G45S323oSJABnykKAhI-

My code:

```
function myFunction() {
    function Lento() {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
        var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
        var values = rows.getValues();
        var numCols = rows.getNumColumns();
        var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
        for (var r=1; r<values.length; r++) {
            var row = values[r],
                identificador = row[0],
                palabraclave = row[1],
                ciudad = row[2],
                fecha = row[4],
                pais = row[5],
                idusuario = row[6],
                nombre = row[7],
                email = row[8],
                telefono = row[9],
                mensaje = row[10],
                urllanding = row[11],
                fechausuario = row[12];

            Logger.log(identificador);
            Logger.log(palabraclave);
            Logger.log(ciudad);
            Logger.log(fecha);
            Logger.log(pais);  
       }

       if (row[0] !== row[6]) {
           spreadsheet.deleteRow(row);
       }
  }

  Lento();
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: any clue which line of your code produces the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with `spreadsheet.deleteRow(row)`. First, you want to delete the row on this particular sheet, so it should be `sheet.deleteRow(...)`. The other problem is that `deleteRow` expects an integer as an argument, but you've provided `row`, which is an array. To delete the row, you want to do

```
sheet.deleteRow(r+1);
```

because `r` is the integer linked to the position in the array, not `row`. See the documentation on `deleteRow(rowPosition)`:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition

Comment: Hello,

I could go further in my code , now I keep an array GCLIDs a sheet and another sheet and compared , but when deleting the row tells me that these rows exceed the limits .

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the solution to what I do.

as well as it gives errors since the comprovación of the array is null therefore not work , the code would look like .

```
function myFunction() {
function Lento() {
    var h1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
    var h2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
    var rowsh1 = h1.getDataRange();
    var valuesh1 = rowsh1.getValues();
    var numColsh1 = rowsh1.getNumColumns();
    var numRowsh1 = rowsh1.getNumRows();
    var rowsh2 = h2.getDataRange();
    var valuesh2 = rowsh2.getValues();
    var numColsh2 = rowsh2.getNumColumns();
    var numRowsh2 = rowsh2.getNumRows();
    var idusuario = [];
    var identificador = [];
    //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja1 
    for (var r = 1; r < valuesh2.length; r++) {
        var rowh2 = valuesh2[r],
            nombre = rowh2[1],
            email = rowh2[2],
            telefono = rowh2[3],
            mensaje = rowh2[4],
            urllanding = rowh2[5],
            fechausuario = rowh2[6];
        idusuario[r] = rowh2[0]; //Guardamos los gclid del usuario en un array 

    }
    //recorremos fila a fila y cogemos los datos de la hoja2 
    for (var r = 1; r < valuesh1.length; r++) {
        var rowh1 = valuesh1[r],
            palabraclave = rowh1[1],
            ciudad = rowh1[2],
            fecha = rowh1[4],
            pais = rowh1[5];
        identificador[r] = rowh1[0]; //Guardamos los gclid en un array 

    }


    for (var i = identificador.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var encontrado = false;
        for (var y = 1; y < idusuario.length; y++) {

            if (identificador[i] == null || idusuario[y] == null) continue;
            if (identificador[i] == idusuario[y]) {
                encontrado = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!encontrado) {

            h1.deleteRow(i + 1);
        }
    }

}

Lento();
}
```